# MSVC failed to compile when converting a base type to a derived type in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, constexpr

Code:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename value_type, typename iterator_type>
class array_iterator_base
{
protected:
    value_type *ptr;

public:
    constexpr array_iterator_base() : ptr(nullptr) {}
    constexpr iterator_type &operator++()
    {
        ++ptr;
        return *static_cast<iterator_type *>(this); // [1]
    }
};

template <typename value_type>
class array_iterator : public array_iterator_base<value_type, array_iterator<value_type>>
{
public:
    constexpr array_iterator(value_type *ptr)
    {
        this->ptr = ptr;
    }
};

template <typename value_type, std::size_t Size>
class array
{
public:
    using iterator = array_iterator<value_type>;

    value_type m_data[Size];
    constexpr iterator begin() { return iterator(m_data); }
};

class Demo
{
    using storage = array<int, 3>;
    using iterator = typename storage::iterator;

private:
    storage m_arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
    iterator m_iter = m_arr.begin();

public:
    constexpr Demo() {}
    constexpr void field()
    {
        ++m_iter; // MSVC: failed
    }
    constexpr void local_variable()
    {
        storage arr = { 1,2,3 };
        iterator iter = arr.begin();
        ++iter; // MSVC: OK
    }
};

constexpr int ok()
{
    Demo demo;
    demo.local_variable();
    return 1;
}

constexpr int error()
{
    Demo demo;
    demo.field();
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int x = ok();
    // GCC: OK
    // Clang: OK
    // MSVC: OK

    constexpr int y = error(); // [2]
    // GCC: OK
    // Clang: OK
    // MSVC: error
}
```

Error at line `[2]` due to line `[1]`:

```
Expression did not evaluate to a constant.
Failure was caused by cast of object of dynamic type
    array_iterator<value_type>
to type
    iterator_type
with
    [value_type=int]
    [iterator_type=array_iterator<int>]
```

I am writing an array class myself. I decide to write an array iterator base class so that any array iterator class can just inherit from it to save some keystrokes. To do this, I must cast the base class to the derived iterator class when there is a need to return the iterator itself, so there is the `return *static_cast<iterator_type *>(this);` in the `iterator_type &operator++()` overload.

However, in a `constexpr` context, MSVC failed to compile when the iterator is a field in a class but compiled successfully when the iterator is a local variable. The error message said that the expression is not constant because the function call involves casting a dynamic type (see above).

GCC and Clang compiled successfully in both cases.

Interestingly, in Visual Studio, the value of `y` can actually be previewed (by hovering the cursor on it) just like any other `constexpr` variable (which makes me think that MSVC is probably wrong).

Edit: The latest preview version of MSVC still does not compile.

Edit: I have reported this bug to Microsoft [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/936091/compile-time-error-when-converting-from-base-type.html).

Questions:

1. Which compiler is correct according to the standard?
2. Is there a better way to do what I am doing (i.e. writing a base class for iterator classes to inherit from)?

Comment: It would be nice to know if the latest VS Preview accepts the code.

Comment: @Acorn Just tried with MSVC "Preview" (C++20 standard) and it gives the same error (default is C++17 standard); using C++14 standard also gives the same error.

Comment: @durianice I tried to improve the formatting taking out the errors etc. Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Comment: I don't know if MSVC is correct or not but can't you just let `operator++` return an `array_iterator_base&` ? That works with MSVC. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/UEF6Au)

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug. You should file a bug (menu Help/Send Feedback/Report a Problem...).

Comment: @TedLyngmo If the base type, instead of the derived type, is returned, member functions that are only defined in the derived class can not be used, though in the demo code I showed here there is no such function.

Comment: That's true, but perhaps you can manage without that middle layer, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/q8zzCm)? - or what kind of functions are you thinking of putting in that middle layer that can't be apart of the base class?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your way works. Maybe I should do it in your way. I was writing the base class because I looked at the STL code and saw two classes: `array_iterator` and `array_const_iterator`. Then writing a base class could be useful. But never think of that `array_const_iterator<T>` is just `array_iterator<const T>` (or maybe there is a difference?).

Comment: No, that's right. This looks much like how I tend to implement iterators. You should take a look at [named requirements: LegacyContiguousIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator) or `LegacyRandomAcessIterator` though so that you don't forget any `typedef`s or member functions.

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/VZ53iN) (untested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason that this shouldn't compile.

MSVC's error message makes no sense, because `array_iterator<value_type>` with `value_type = int` is `array_iterator<int>` and `iterator_type` is also `array_iterator<int>`. So the cast is valid.

`this` also refers an object that was created in this constant expression evaluation that started with the call to `error()`, so there is no reason to reject it as subevaluation of the constant expression.

Both GCC and Clang seem to agree with that analysis, so it is likely a MSVC bug. I also don't see any problem with the CRTP you are using here. I don't see the benefit though, since as it is there is only one class definition( `array_iterator`) inheriting from the CRTP base.

Downcasting seems appropriate. You only have to make sure that an instance of type `array_iterator_base` is never directly created. You could e.g. make the constructors of `array_iterator_base` `protected` to achieve that.